# inotifywait loop to monitor directory changes and execute custom bash script

Tags: linux, inotifywait

Here is a script for executing custom script on file changed in directory. The thing is that it doesn't react on file changes. Where is a mistake ?

```
printf "starting watching folder...\n";
while inotifywait -r /media/my_folder
do
  echo "a file changed..."
  custom_script.sh
done
```

Comment: Read `man inotifywait`. `-m` means "don't exit on the first event received". So, it's performing as expected.

Comment: @twalberg, even without *-m* the line *echo "a file changed..."* is never shown =(

Comment: Does it continue into the 'do' loop if you trigger a file system notification on in /media/my_folder?  Might only proceed after the first event received.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/49349226/2877507 should take care of your needs!